# MYSQL Select records with closest date

Tags: mysql, date, select, records, closest

I am having the following 2 tables in my database:

product_price

```
CREATE TABLE `product_price` (
  `asin` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`asin`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

product_info

```
CREATE TABLE `product_info` (
  `asin` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` text,
  `image` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to find the products which its price has been reduced between a start date and a end date.

I am using the following query right now which works:

```
$query      = "SELECT pi.*, prev.price AS 'old_price', curr.price, ROUND((100.0*(curr.price - prev.price) / prev.price),0) As PercentDiff FROM product_price As curr 
       JOIN product_price As prev ON curr.date = '".$end_date."' AND prev.date = '".$start_date."' 
       JOIN product_info pi ON curr.asin = pi.asin WHERE curr.asin = prev.asin HAVING PercentDiff < 0 ORDER BY PercentDiff";
```

But the problem is that table product_price has not has a record if the price has not changed.

Eg for example

```
asin        date         price
AAAAAAAAA  2018-07-17     7
AAAAAAAAA  2018-07-15     6
```

start_date= "2018-07-16" end_date="2018-07-17"

I want it to have it in my results as price was reduced.

How i had to change my query??

I tried to change prev.date = '".$start_date."' to prev.date <= '".$start_date."'

But returns all the records and not the closest one as i want.

Here is some sample data from product_price:

```
+------------+------------+--------+
| asin       | date       | price  |
+------------+------------+--------+
| B000GBKDB4 | 2018-07-02 |  38.66 |
| B000GBKDCI | 2018-07-02 |  72.98 |
| B000GBKFLW | 2018-07-02 |  33.27 |
| B000GBKFMG | 2018-07-02 |  63.45 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-02 |  34.90 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-04 |  21.31 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-05 |  20.24 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-06 |  18.41 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-08 |  17.49 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-09 |  15.79 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-11 |  14.84 |
| B000GBLZEI | 2018-07-16 |  14.29 |
```

Comment: It would help if you put a little bit of sample data up and your required results as a table

Comment: I added some data from product_price table. So in my example data when start date is 2018-07-15 and 2018-07-16 for asin B000GBLZEI  has to show the price drop from 2018-07-11 to 2018-07-16 But with the query i provided it will only show when you set start date = 2018-07-11 and end date 2018-07-16

Comment: Can the price go down then back up in the period? If so what do you want to do? Do you really mean you want those where the price at the last date is less than the price at the start date?

Answer (score 1):

Still not very clear what you are after but this should select the correct prices applicable for a pair of dates. 2018-07-03 to 2018-07-07 that don't appear in the product_price table.

Hopefully this will set you on the right track.

```
SELECT *,

    (SELECT price 
        FROM product_price 
        WHERE product_price.asin = product_info.asin AND 
            product_price.date <= '2018-07-03'
        ORDER BY product_price.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS start_price,

    (SELECT price 
        FROM product_price 
        WHERE product_price.asin = product_info.asin AND 
            product_price.date <= '2018-07-07'
        ORDER BY product_price.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS end_price

FROM product_info
WHERE asin = 'B000GBLZEI'
```

Following on from your comment, you could use a temporary table like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price_changes (
    asin VARCHAR(10), 
    start_price DECIMAL(7,2), 
    end_price DECIMAL(7,2));

TRUNCATE price_changes;

INSERT INTO price_changes 
SELECT asin, 

    (SELECT price 
        FROM product_price 
        WHERE product_price.asin = product_info.asin AND 
            product_price.date <= '2018-07-03'
        ORDER BY product_price.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS start_price,

    (SELECT price 
        FROM product_price 
        WHERE product_price.asin = product_info.asin AND 
            product_price.date <= '2018-07-07'
        ORDER BY product_price.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS end_price

FROM product_info;

SELECT *,
    ROUND((100.0 * (end_price - start_price) / start_price), 0) AS price_difference
FROM product_info 
    JOIN price_changes ON
        price_changes.asin = product_info.asin;
```

Comment: Okey this on the right direction. But i need to calculated the diffrence(in percentage) on top of this.

Comment: I've added some code to calculate the percentage difference.

Comment: Seems a bit complex to achieve it but i guess there is not other option. I will try it and let you know. Thank you :)